# What is the best algorithm for my differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem

The solution of the following boundary value problem is required:
$$r_1<r<r_2:R''(r)+\frac{R'(r)}{r} - (1+\frac{1}{r^2})R(r) = 1$$
$$R(r_1)=R(r_2)=0$$
The differential equation is the modified Bessel equation, thus one approach is to use the method of variation of parameters. But it will require integrals of modified Bessel functions, the solution of which will be in terms of Hypergeometric functions which are expensive to evaluate. another method is to use [Struve function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struve_function) but it is in the form of power series and computation of power series is inefficient, especially for large arguments. Therefore I was thinking of numerical schemes. I read a little about Remez algorithm and weighted residuals method, but I'm not too familiar with numerical computation. What is the best approach in terms of both accuracy and efficiency?
Also if it is possible to extend the method to the general case of second order ODEs:
$$x_1<x<x_2:y''(x)+p(x)y'(x) + q(x)y(x) = 1$$
$$y(x_1)=y(x_2)=0$$

Comment: Why not use standard BVP solvers? They approximate $R$ as a piecewise polynomial function where the coefficients are determined to get a twice differentiable function and that the ODE is satisfied on carefully selected points in each interval (collocation method, Gauß points or similar).

Comment: @LutzLehmann Are they a sub-category of weighted residuals? and are they the most efficient?

Comment: I'm not aware of weight function arguments. Depending on how small $r_1$ and how large $x_2$, even simple single shooting methods should work, as the equation is linear. This is very efficient. If the interval becomes close to $[0,\infty)$, special care needs to be taken for the initial and/or final segment.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could you name a reference which I can use?

Comment: I have no ready references. Searching for "numerical methods for singular boundary value problems" gives some credible looking results.